# Wordpress block with mixed richtext types

Tags: wordpress, richtext, gutenberg-blocks

I have an old - "classic block" - info box (other styles can be selected by authors) and was wondering how best to convert it to a Gutenberg block, including all the text options, like adding lists, paragraphs, etc. within the content section.

So far I only found examples of creating blocks with single RichText elements like `p` or `h2` or `li`, etc.

Can they even be combined within a single block?

I saw that the table block has no option to include anything other than `plain text`, `<em>`, `<strong>` and `<br>` tags within table cells. No option for lists, etc.

[image: info box screenshot]

Comment: The core/freeform block has a TinyMCE WYSIWYG. Are you currently using the classic editor?

Comment: In the above example I am using the block type "classic".